# Can Swift code be used in Unity that will be exported for both Android and iOS

Tags: android, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have been reading ways to use Swift in Unity. Would using Swift in Unity cause problems at the time when im building the Unity project for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if so

its a bad idea to use programming language but C#